# Quitar o agregar atributo runat="server"

Tags: c#, webforms

Mi pregunta es puntual, ¿hay alguna manera de quitar o agregar el atributo `runat="server`" dinámicamente a una etiqueta?

Me explico. Si tengo por allá un `div` en `HTML`:

```
<div id="un_div" runat="server">Cualquier cosa</div>
```

Y tengo el evento `Onclick` de un botón:

```
protected void re_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

}
```

¿Es posible hacer algo parecido a esto?:

```
protected void re_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
   un_div.Attributes.Add("runat","");
}
```

Yo sé que lo anterior fue muy loco, pero era más o menos para que se hicieran una idea de lo que busco y saber si es esto posible.

Comment: Se puede saber cuáles son tus motivos para eso?

Comment: @Flxtr yo creo que no es MVC, solo se equivoco con la etiqueta....
Mira si tu problema es que siempre manda al server y hay ocasiones que no quieres que mande al server, existe el atributo onClientClick aqui puedes agregar una validación antes de enviar el resultado al server, aparte si el botón siempre hace submit, podrías ponerlo como type=button para evitar esta situación, pero todo depende de que quieres hacer

Comment: @CristinaCarrascoAngulo sí, ya le dejé un mensaje al OP para que lo tome en cuanta. Saludos ;)

Comment: poner runat=server en un tag html tiene por objetivo poder acceder a este desde codigo .net, es algo que asp.net necesita, cambiarlo dinamicamente por medio de atributos no tendria mucho sentido. Si accedes al div desde codigo .net no puedes removerlo, ahora sino lo haces entonces puede quitarlo